# Why does my distributed app look different than it did while debugging in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I 'completed' an app and submitted it to the app store. The app was rejected because they couldn't get the app to start. They sent me images and they look different than anything that I have seen while debugging.

I created an ad hoc .ipa and loaded it onto my device and then I was able to see the same symptoms.  Some images are missing, including the 'start' button.

It does not cause a crash, so I can't use crash reports to debug the problem.

Are there certain settings that I need to modify to make sure that a distributed app and a debugged app are the same?

I am using Xcode 5.1.1 and Cocos2D.

(Some of the images that are missing are images whose zOrder I modified; I don't know if this is relevant or not).

One of the missing images is 'tower_blank.png' shown in the project navigator in the screen shot below:

[image]

Comment: Before submitting an app, delete your app from your device and do a Clean in Xcode. Then test a fresh, clean build. This will ensure there are no old files left laying around.

Comment: Are your images in the project and are they named properly? One thing that can happen is that you had an image, let's say for the start button, and you replaced it with a new graphic that has a different name (or different casing). The old image can still be loaded and used by your app if the app was previously deployed to your device or simulator even though it shouldn't still exist after you've removed it from the app and deleted it.

Comment: Before submitting, build a 'release' ad hoc and test on as many devices as you can lay your hands on. Look for missing files (missing as 'not included in the target', and CaseDiscrepencies.File.name.png.

Comment: I just noticed that one of the images that is not showing up does not have an 'A' next to it in the Project Navigator (see the screen shot that I added to my question). Could this be the problem? What does the 'A' mean?

Comment: The A is for "added", it means this is a new file which will be added to your repository with your next commit

Comment: I updated replaced the file and checked the 'copy' box to make the 'A' appear, but it made no difference.

Comment: @rmaddy I removed the app, did a clean build, and ran in on my iPad with Xcode. In this scenario all images are shown correctly. But the images are gone again when I when I load the .ipa

Comment: I am using a constant for the the missing image. The spelling and case is consistent with the asset.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg How will I know if they are not included on the target. When you say 'CaseDiscrepencies.File.name.png' are you just saying to make sure that the case and spelling are correct or is there something more? Thanks.

Comment: regarding case : yes. Case discrepancies can easily explain why something that works on simulator does not on device for example. I'll need to dust-off ex-Code and will come back with instructions for target membership.

Comment: @RyanTensmeyer : in project settings, build phases, under the item 'copy bundle resources', locate and click on the file. On right hand side, you will see in the file inspector the target membership. Make certain that it is clicked for each resource you need.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I looked at each of the resources in the 'File Membership->Target Membership' and all of them are checked the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution that fixed the problem. I would love to get some feedback as to whether this is a good idea or not.

Under 'Build Settings->Apple LLVM 5.1 - Code Generation->Optimization Level' I changed the Release setting from 'Fastest,Smallest' to 'None'

Comment: This sounds like it could be a bug. You should file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com.